# Angular Directive Variables used in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

so I have been looking around for information on directives, and there is quite a few people posting, and answering questions. but I am still not finding my answer, and maybe it is because I am trying to use the controller where I should be using the link.

My directive is fairly deep, but the basic idea is it is pulling out the db/table/column data from my database into 3 select drop downs.  The initially, only 1 drop down is available, until a db is chosen, then it goes to get the tables, and when it is chosen, the third drop down appears and all is good in the universe.  I have this working, and all the code is in the controller.

The problem comes with trying to pre-populate this if the data happens to be present.

my directive is called like this inside of an ng-repeat:

```
<choosedb 
    db='{{xmlBlock.dict.mapTo.column.db}}'
</choosedb>
```

my directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('choosedb',["$http",  function($http) {
    return {
        scope:{
            db: "@db"
        },
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'templates/jsTemplates/choosedb.html',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {

           $scope.selectedDB = db; // <<<<< this does not work

        controller: function($scope, $http){

           $scope.selectedDB = db; // <<<<< this does not work
        }
    }
}]);
```

should I somehow move all of my controller logic into link?  or how can I access the directive scope inside of my directive controller??

Comment: The first argument in your linking function, and the `$scope` argument in your controller function (which is an injectable local) are both the directive scope.

Comment: I can put an >> alert(scope.db) << in both places and it is undefined.

Comment: In the code shown, the name is `$scope`, not `scope`.  Also, with an isolate scope, you need to use `$watch()` or `$observe()` to obtain the interpolated value of `db`.  E.g., in the link function:  `attrs.$observe('db', function(value) { console.log(value) })`.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#Attributes  In the controller, you can use `$watch('db', ...)`.

Comment: after much fighting.. and buying an Angular Book ... I discovered that the scope:{ db:"@db"} was optional.  since I was looking for the parent scope, if I omitted this entirely, it was not overwriting the parent.  more research is needed...